# Buffer I/O error on dev sda1 - not a hardware problem

Tags: usb, hard-drive

In the last month or so, one of my external hard drives has stopped working properly with my Raspberry Pi. It works for a while, then it stops working randomly.

- I ran `ls` on the drive's folder and it gives me `ls: reading directory .: Input/output error`.
- So I tried `dmesg | tail` and I got a series of

  ```
  Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block XXXXXX [this is different each time], async page read
  ```
- The disk works again if I reboot the Pi (even without physically turning it off and on).
- I assumed it was a drive failure, so I bought a new one and copied the data across from a backup I have. However, the new one also gives the same error. I then thought it might be the Pi itself (Pi 1 Model B), so I swapped it with another Raspberry Pi I have (swapped the memory cards around). But I still got the same error.
- I then tried reinstalling Raspbian from scratch and reinstalling all my programs (Transmission, minidlna, Samba) but I still get the problem.
  There is another drive connected (to which I run backups of my computer's HDD and the other disk on the RPi - or I used to until it started playing up) but I've had no problems with it at all.
- Both drives are powered by their own external power supplies.

I really don't understand why this keeps happening. If it were a hardware problem, the old disk wouldn't work in Windows (which it does, and having checked it with `chkdsk` it gives no errors) and the new disk should work on the RPi (which it doesn't properly).

Both drives are NTFS and run with `ntfs-3g`

Comment: How are you powering the disk?

Comment: The disk is powered using its own power adapter and not via the Pi.

Comment: You can copy the broken sd card with a more larger memory card. Maybe it's becasue the storage is full, and the sd card is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Just found a answer may help , it solved my problem.

[Connection problem with usb3 external storage on Linux (UAS driver problem)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239782/connection-problem-with-usb3-external-storage-on-linux-uas-driver-problem)

Looks like a kernel issue.

---

I have the same problem here, not  Raspbian, a old laptop with archlinux.

I searched a lot, tried every way I can .
Now I think it was caused by Hardware or device driver faults, not a software faults.

[What does the “I/O error” mean?](https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#ioerror)

```
What does the “I/O error” mean?
The Input/Output errors mean unexpected, low-level errors. They are caused by hardware errors (disk, RAM, cable, power supply, motherboard, etc), device driver faults, corrupted file system, software fault or incorrect hardware use.
```

I found that:

```
Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block …
reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 17
```

same with what happened to my computer...

This may help:

[What are USB device resets?](https://superuser.com/questions/668911/what-are-usb-device-resets?)

> The problem could be in marginal voltage (VBUS) supply to the drives, or VBUS glitches, or signal degradation on signal wires. I would try extremely short high-quality certified cables first, and check if the statistics of error changes.

I guess it may caused by something else like usb port poor connection or driver problem, not hard disk.

I didn't find anyone fixed this with software configuration so far.

Maybe you should check you Raspbian not your disk.

That is my assumptions, hope it can help you.