# Hard drive disconnects with with my NAS pi seedbox

Tags: raspbian, storage

I'm new to Raspberry Pi and Linux so I might just be stupid. So I have a ntfs 4tb Western Digital External hard drive (formated in ntfs) that is externally powered so power is not coming from the RPi. I have the raspberry pi connected with a 2.5a power supply. I have the raspberry pi running rasbian, samba, and deluge (I have ntfs-3g installed). The problem is that randomly it just disconnects the harddrive and won't let me mount the hard drive back it gives the error.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/USBHDD1
mount: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist
```

When I type dmesg it gives this mess (its a much longer list)

```
Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 786431, async page read
usb 1-1.5: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
```

Rebooting the raspberry pi and running deluge seems to work for a little bit, but it will come back with the I/O error after a random interval in time from a couple of minutes to a few weeks. I don't know if it is a heat issue, I don't think it is. The hard drive works plugged into windows machines. It has a lot of data I need so formatting it is not really an option
If you need more information I can provide it.

Comment: You're not stupid.  That shouldn't happen.  I think I've seen multiple similiar problems with WD drives here but that could be coincidence since they are popular (presumably most of them work).  Similar unsolved mystery here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/31794/5538 also using `ntfs-3g` (which could also easily be coincidence).

Comment: That seems like the same problem I am having. At idle and reading it seems to work. When checking torrents it just disconnects. It is a western digital "My book" on windows machines it works like a normal hard drive. I have yet to try it on another linux machine, but I may do that.

Comment: I do not know if this is a relevant topic, but the pi has something with the ethernet and usb that does not function well under load. Would anyone recommend say the odroid xu4 for this task or the banana pi(I would have to physically remove the drive for the banana pi for the sata connection)

Comment: USB & ethernet share a bottleneck, but the max eth speed is less than half that, so it delimits the throughput to the drive.  So in theory you should be able to do 10-12 MB/s but in reality it is more like 3-4;  I think some people have reported 6-8.  Torrenting complicates that I'd guess. The CPU should not be showing serious load; that is something to look at.  WRT other devices, the best bet is to look for people doing exactly the same thing (torrenting to ntfs).

Comment: I have the same issue, although my disk has ext4 filesystem. I found that when I'm running a force recheck on all of the downloaded torrents(total is 43), it disconnect after some time. If I don't start deluged the disk stays connected.
I have been searching for a solution, but no luck so far, so I'd appreciate if someone had a clever idea for this problem.